# Do Two Operators Need A Term In Their OPE Whose Weight Is Their Combined Weight?

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory

My logic is as follows. Suppose I have two operators, $O_1$ and $O_2$. I place a copy of each operator near the origin, and a copy of each operator distance $d$ away, for some large $d$. I can first combine the two sets of $O_1$, $O_2$, and get two copies of $\sum_i C_{12i}O_i$. For large $d$, this means that the four-point function scales as $d^{-2\Delta_{min}}$, where $\Delta_{min}$ is the lowest dimension of any $O_i$ in the $O_1$-$O_2$ OPE.

Alternately, I can contract the two $O_1$s with each other and the two $O_2$s with each other. This seems like it should result in a four-point function proportional to $d^{-2(\Delta_1+\Delta_2)}$. So if these two expressions are equivalent, shouldn't we have $\Delta_{min}=\Delta_1+\Delta_2$?

Answer (score 4):

You are very close to discover the so-called ''lightcone bootstrap'' or ''analytic bootstrap.'' There is a lot of literature about it, I'll post some refs. at the bottom. I'll first rewrite your idea in a more precise way.

Let us consider two operators $O_1$ and $O_2$ in a $d$ dimensional conformal field theory. In particular let us write down their four point function with the parametrization $[1]$
$$
\langle O_1(x_1)O_2(x_2)O_2(x_3)O_1(x_4)\rangle = \frac{1}{(x_{12}^2)^{\frac12(\Delta_1+\Delta_2)}(x_{34}^2)^{\frac12(\Delta_1+\Delta_2)}}\left(\frac{x_{24}^2x_{13}^2}{x_{14}^4}\right)^{\frac12(\Delta_1-\Delta_2)}  f(u,v)\,,
$$
where $x_{ij}=x_i-x_j$ and $u$, $v$ are ratios defined as
$$
u= \frac{x_{12}^2x_{34}^2}{x_{13}^2x_{24}^2}\,,\qquad
v= \frac{x_{14}^2x_{23}^2}{x_{13}^2x_{24}^2}\,.
$$
The limit we want to consider is $x_1,x_2$ close together, $x_3,x_4$ close together, and these two pairs of point far away at distance $d$.
$$
x_{12} \sim x_{34} \ll x_{13} \sim x_{14}\sim x_{23}\sim x_{24} \;\Longrightarrow\;u \to O\left(\frac{1}{d^4}\right)\,,v\to 1 + O\left(\frac1{d^4}\right)\,.\tag{1}\label{limit}
$$
The function $f(u,v)$ can be decomposed into a basis of function, each of them representing the contribution to an operator $O_i$ to the OPE. These functions are called *conformal blocks* (or conformal partial waves). In this parametrization a conformal block represents the OPE between the first two and the last two operators, so $O_1\times O_2$ twice. This is how $f$ decomposes
$$
f(u,v) = \sum_{\Delta_i,\ell_i} C_{12i}^2 \, G_{\Delta_i,\ell_i}(u,v)\,.
$$
In $[1]$ it is given an asymptotic form for the conformal blocks in the $u\to0, v\to1$ limit:
$$
G_{\Delta,\ell}(u,v) \sim u^{\frac12(\Delta-\ell)}(1-v)^\ell\,F(1-v)\,,
$$
where $F(1-v)$ is some smooth function around zero. This means that the sum is dominated by the operator with the lowest value of $\Delta-\ell$ (which is called *twist*) and by the lowest spin. Therefore such operator also has the lowest dimension, which we will call $\Delta_{\mathrm{min}}$ and is a scalar. As correctly stated by OP this means that $f$ behaves as
$$
f(u,v)\sim \frac{1}{d^{2\Delta_{\mathrm{min}}}}\,.
$$
Now we want to do the OPE in the crossed channel. This can be achieved by considering the parametrization of the correlator with positions $1$ and $3$ swapped. 
$$
\langle O_1(x_1)O_2(x_2)O_2(x_3)O_1(x_4)\rangle = \frac{1}{(x_{14}^2)^{\Delta_1}(x_{23}^2)^{\Delta_2}} \tilde{f}(u,v)\,.
$$
These two different parametrizations (i.e. choices of taking the OPE) are related by
$$
u^{-\frac12(\Delta_1+\Delta_2)}\,f(u,v) = v^{-\Delta_2}\, \tilde{f}(u,v)\,.
\tag{2}\label{ceq}
$$
And if we decompose in conformal blocks $\tilde{f}$ we have
$$
\tilde{f}(u,v) =  \sum_{\Delta_i,\ell_i} C_{11i}C_{22i} \, G_{\Delta_i,\ell_i}(v,u)\,. \tag{3}\label{cross}
$$
Note the exchange $v\leftrightarrow u$ which is a consequence of exchanging $1\leftrightarrow3$. Now the behaviour of $G(v,u)$ in the limit \eqref{limit} is not as straightforward as before. In particular, the sum is no longer dominated by a single operator. Therefore one cannot conclude that the behavior is $\sim d^{-(\Delta_1+\Delta_2)}$.

But we can do this story in Lorentzian signature and consider a limit slightly different than \eqref{limit}. Namely a sort of "lightcone" limit in which $x_2$ is light-like separated from $x_1$ and $x_3$, while $x_4$ is far away. This results in
$$
u \ll v \ll 1\,. \tag{4}\label{limit2}
$$

The discussion in the seminal papers $[2,3]$ establishes that the sum in \eqref{cross} is dominated by a tail in large spin $\ell \gg 1$. This is essentially because the behavior at small $u$ is not reproduced at any finite order of the sum,$^1$ and thus it has to come from the tail. This is, if you want, the resolution to your paradox: the apparent mismatch between the two OPE is due to the fact that the leading behavior of the crossed channel is given by the tail in the sum, rather than by an operator in particular. In your question you assumed that the OPE in this channel would be dominated by the identity operator, which is not true.

To be more precise the asymptotic of the block in the crossed channel in the limit \eqref{limit2} and at large spin is
$$
G_{\Delta,\ell}(v,u) \underset{\ell\sqrt{u}\gg1}{\sim} v^{\frac12(\Delta-\ell)} \frac{e^{-2\ell\sqrt{u}}}{\sqrt[4]{u}}\,.
$$
Now I'll be very sketchy. Let us assume for a second that there is a tail of operators such that the OPE coefficients and dimensions at large spin can be seen to have a behavior
$$
C_{11i}C_{22i} \sim \ell_i^{\Delta_1+\Delta_2 -1}\,,\qquad \Delta_i \sim \Delta_1+ \Delta_2\,.
$$
The sum on the tail can be morally replaced by an integral
$$
\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}\ell\, \ell^{\Delta_1+\Delta_2 -1} e^{-2\ell \sqrt{u}} \propto u^{-\frac12(\Delta_1+\Delta_2)}\,.
$$
This reproduces the singularity in the non-crossed channel \eqref{ceq}. It turns out that things work out only if $\Delta_i \sim \Delta_1 +\Delta_2$ modulo corrections $\sim 1/\ell_i^\#$. To sum it up, the answer to the statement in the title is negative, but its correction is

*''In the OPE of $O_1$ and $O_2$ there must always be a family of operators with very large spin $\ell$ and conformal dimension arbitrarily close to $\Delta_1 + \Delta_2 + \ell$.''*

---

$[1]$ F.A. Dolan and H. Osborn, *Conformal Partial Waves and the Operator Product Expansion* [hep-th/0309180](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0309180)

$[2]$ A. Liam Fitzpatrick, Jared Kaplan, David Poland and David Simmons-Duffin, *The Analytic Bootstrap and AdS Superhorizon Locality* [1212.3616](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3616)

$[3]$ Zohar Komargodski and Alexander Zhiboedov, *Convexity and Liberation at Large Spin* [1212.4103](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4103)

---

$\quad ^1$ The crossed blocks have at most a $\log u$ singularity, which will never reproduce the power-like singularity in the non-crossed channel $u^{-\frac12(\Delta_1+\Delta_2)}$.

---

**Further reading**

$[4]$ L. F. Alday, A. Bissi and T. Lukowski, *Large spin systematics in CFT* [1502.07707](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.07707)

$[5]$ L. F. Alday and A. Zhiboedov, *Conformal Bootstrap With Slightly Broken Higher Spin Symmetry* [1506.04659](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04659)

$[6]$ L. F. Alday and A. Zhiboedov, *An Algebraic Approach to the Analytic Bootstrap* [1510.08091](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.08091)

$[7]$ D. Simmons-Duffin, *The Lightcone Bootstrap and the Spectrum of the 3d Ising CFT* [1612.08471](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08471)

$[8]$ L. F. Alday, *Large Spin Perturbation Theory* [1611.01500](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01500)

Comment: +1 for the well-written and well-sourced answer. However, why don't you write in Wikipedia before answering obscure questions on StackExchange? For example, the Wikipedia article on Conformal field theory is very weak and deserves attention. And if there were decent Wikipedia articles on CFT, maybe there would be fewer basic questions to answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand the geometry you're considering. It seems that you have in mind a limit where both pairs of $(O_1,O_2)$ are close together, so both $O_1 \times O_2$ OPEs converge rapidly. In that case naive scaling arguments based on the OPE are reliable. But if this channel converges rapidly, the other channel, based the $O_1 \times O_1$ and $O_2 \times O_2$ OPEs, converges slowly, and to reproduce the scaling you like you need to resum infinitely many terms.

To get what you want, consider a GFF with two fields $\phi$ and $\psi$ with dimensions $\Delta_\phi, \Delta_\psi$. You can construct such a theory by putting two free scalars in AdS with different masses. The full four-point function reads
$$\langle \phi(x_1) \psi(x_2) \psi(x_3) \phi(x_4) \rangle = \frac{1}{|x_2 - x_3|^{2\Delta_\psi} |x_1 - x_4|^{2\Delta_\phi}}.$$
In one channel (where $|x_1 - x_4|$ and $|x_2 - x_3|$ are small)  this is obvious. In the other channel you exchange infinitely many composite operators:
$$
\phi(x_1) \psi(x_2) \sim \sum_{n,\ell} \; [\phi \psi]_{n,\ell}
$$
where $[\phi \psi]_{n,\ell}$ has dimension $\Delta_\phi + \Delta_\psi + 2n + \ell$ and spin $\ell$. Naively, the lowest-dimension exchanged has $n = \ell = 0$ so you expect a scaling
$$\langle \phi(x_1) \psi(x_2) \psi(x_3) \phi(x_4) \rangle \sim \frac{1}{|x_2 - x_3|^{2\Delta_\phi + 2\Delta_\psi}} + \ldots.
$$
The fact that this does not reproduce the full correlator at all means that you need to include infinitely many descendants and other exchanged operators to get a reliable result. For a given configuration $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ there are some estimates about the rate of converge, meaning how many terms you need to include to get a small error.